# Connection refused for URI https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api, laravel-socialite

I am new to GoogleAPIs and Laravel, I run a PHP web application on Laravel 8 in a virtual Linux environment. Socialite and Drive API was working fine and out of sudden it doesn't work anymore and always return connection refused error after long period of loading as follows:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException
Connection refused for URI https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

I had tried to create a new credential with new refresh token and checked all the network settings, and always clear config cache and restart apache for all troubleshoots I have tested, yet the error still exists.

I would appreciate it much if anyone could enlighten me on what are the aspects I shall look into it.

Comment: Are you using a library to authenticate? Or are you manually getting the token?

Comment: Hi @Martí , i generate the refresh token via [myphpnotes](https://google.myphpnotes.com/) following by his tutorial. The site is working fine for months before i bump into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in this question.

First and foremost, you are sending your secret to a third party. This means that they are able to do any API calls as you (using your name and quotas). Even if they claim that they won't, they can. Please remove any secret you may have and create new ones.

As for the OAuth 2.0, you seem to be using an old URL. You should probably take a look into the official documentation for:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) for a basic explanation.
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) for making a web and getting permissions to get/modify a user's data (can be yourself).
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) for using a service account to execute as one of the users on your organization, without the need of manually giving permission.

Also notice that there are PHP libraries officially supported by Google to make your life way easier. [See the Drive API's PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php).